# How can I call fetch from within a cypress test?

Tags: javascript, cypress

I'm using [Cypress](https://www.cypress.io/). I have a little React app and a little Flask backend. I want my test to make a call to the backend to set up the state it's going to operate on. I used fetch. This works fine. Except Cypress is mad and doesn't consider the test a success. I am not a javascript developer really so this might be obvious, but I can't figure out how to make it happy.

This is my test code:

```js
    it.only("edits a job", async () => {
        const now = new Date().getTime()
        const title = `Edit-This-${now}`
        const newTitle = `SUCCESS-EDIT-${now}`
        const company = `Edit Company-${now}`
        const link = `https://example.com/edit-me-${now}`
        const status = "Edit Test"
        const body = JSON.stringify({company, title, link, status})
        await fetch('/add_job', {method: 'post', headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}, body: body})
        cy.visit("http://localhost:3000/jobs_list")
        cy.contains(title)
        cy.contains(company)
        cy.contains(link)
        cy.contains(status)

        cy.get(`[name=edit-${title}`).click()
        cy.get(`[value=${title}`).clear().type(newTitle)
        cy.get(`[name=save-${newTitle}`).click()

        cy.contains(newTitle)
        console.log("what the heck")
        })
```

This seems to work just fine.  But at the end, there's a CypressError:

```
Cypress command timeout of 4530ms exceeded. (and Mocha's done() called multiple times)
```

I also tried not using async/await and putting the steps inside a `then` after fetch, but that didn't help. Passing `done` to the it block and calling `done()` at the end of that made it not run anything. That makes sense because cypress steps look synchronous but are in fact not, so it would have hit `done()` before executing any of them.

Making the function passed to `it` not async and changing fetch to

```js
cy.request('POST', 'http://localhost:3000/add_job', {'Content-Type': 'application/json', company, title, link, status})
```

instead of `fetch` seems to have worked, but I'd like to understand why.

Answer (score 5):

Use `cy.request` rather than `fetch`.

https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/request

```
cy.request({yourUri}).as("response"); // This takes care of the async task. 
 
cy.get("@response").should((response) => { 
   // Carry on with the rest of your test
   cy.get("some selector");

});
```

Comment: You may want to reuse some helpers from your code instead to send the fetch call, rewriting for cypress adds some redundancy

Answer (score 3):

https://docs.cypress.io/guides/core-concepts/introduction-to-cypress.html#Chains-of-Commands

> It’s very important to understand the mechanism Cypress uses to chain commands together. **It manages a Promise chain on your behalf**, with each command yielding a ‘subject’ to the next command, until the chain ends or an error is encountered. **The developer should not need to use Promises directly, but understanding how they work is helpful!**

You can add items to the Cypress promise chain/queue via [Cypress.Promise](https://docs.cypress.io/api/utilities/promise.html#Syntax)

You could likely wrap your `fetch` call use Cypress.Promise, but `cy.request` is recommended for this unless you have some specific reason not to use it.

```js
// wrap null, so that you can use `then` to invoke a callback as an arbitrary command
// and return a Cypress.Promise - so that cypress will wait on it's result
// (or just use cy.request :))
cy.wrap(null).then(() => {
  return new Cypress.Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    try {
      fetch(/*...*/).then(resolve);
    } catch (e) {
      reject(e);
    }
  })
})
```

Comment: I'd add here links or guides to ECMAScript async-await and Promise spec refs. Author said he's not familiar with JS so It could help him a lot.

Comment: I think reusing some existing logic is a good reason, if you want to test your API using your own client-code with fetch.
It blurs the line between e2e and unit tests as it is more an integration test though but Jest can be annoying to setup (need to spawn a server etc.) while it's more natural with Cypress

Answer (score 0):

You can use fetch with async/await in cypress tests like this:

```js
it('should do something', () => {
  const originalObject = { a: 1 }
  const options = {
    method: 'PUT',
    body: JSON.stringify(originalObject),
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'Accept': 'application/json',
    },
  }

  cy.wrap(null).then(async () => {
    const response = await fetch('/echo', options)
    const echoedObject = await response.json()
    expect(echoedObject).to.deep.eq(originalObject)
  })
})
```